# Why can't I find the right div?

Tags: javascript

The following script right-clicks on a specific element, then clicks on another element. This is last element of the class `item__183e8.labelContainer_bc2861.colorDanger_eec36d.colorDefault__0b482`, and then the script must later find a div that has a text: `"Car"`. My issue is that the script never finds the `"Car"` element

Main script (find the div `item__183e8.labelContainer_bc2861.colorDanger_eec36d.colorDefault__0b482`):

```js
        async function hacerScrollYClickInfinito() {
        // Conjunto para almacenar los elementos ya clickeados dos veces
        const elementosClickeados = new Set();
    
        // Función para hacer clic derecho en un elemento y recoger el texto de los spans
        async function hacerClickDerechoYRecogerTexto(elemento) {
            try {
                // Hacer clic derecho en el elemento
                elemento.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('contextmenu', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
                console.log("Clic derecho en el elemento realizado con éxito.");
    
                // Esperar 0.4 segundos
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 400));
    
                // Buscar el elemento específico después del clic derecho
                const elementoBuscado = document.querySelector('.item__183e8.labelContainer_bc2861.colorDanger_eec36d.colorDefault__0b482');
                if (elementoBuscado) {
                    elementoBuscado.click(); // Hacer clic izquierdo sobre el elemento encontrado
                    console.log("Clic izquierdo en el elemento encontrado realizado con éxito.");
                } else {
                    console.log("Elemento no encontrado. Continuando la ejecución.");
                }
    
                // Imprimir el texto de los elementos span dentro del div
                var spans = elemento.querySelectorAll('span');
                spans.forEach(span => {
                    console.log("Texto del span:", span.textContent);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error al hacer clic derecho en el elemento:", error.message);
            }
        }
    
        // Función para hacer scroll sobre el elemento
        function hacerScrollSobreElemento() {
            // Hacer scroll hacia abajo en el div
            var divScroll = document.querySelector('.members__9f47b.thin_b1c063.scrollerBase_dc3aa9.fade_ba0fa0.customTheme_db4d28');
            divScroll.scrollTop += 40; // Cambia este valor según sea necesario para el scroll deseado
        }
    
        // Configuración del observador de mutaciones
        var observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
            // Obtener los nuevos elementos añadidos al DOM
            mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
                    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.classList.contains('memberInner_a32223') && node.classList.contains('layout_bb8e67')) {
                        hacerScrollSobreElemento(); // Hacer scroll sobre el elemento antes de hacer clic
                        hacerClickDerechoYRecogerTexto(node);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    
        // Observar cambios en el DOM, específicamente en el cuerpo del documento y en sus subárboles
        observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    
        // Bucle principal
        while (true) {
            // Esperar a que se añadan nuevos elementos al DOM
            await new Promise(resolve => {
                const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
                    mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
                        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                            resolve();
                        }
                    });
                });
                observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
            });
    
            // Obtener los elementos ya presentes en la página
            var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.memberInner_a32223.layout_bb8e67');
            for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
                const elemento = elementos[i];
                // Verificar si el elemento ha sido clickeado dos veces previamente
                if (!elementosClickeados.has(elemento)) {
                    hacerScrollSobreElemento(); // Hacer scroll sobre el elemento antes de hacer clic
                    await hacerClickDerechoYRecogerTexto(elemento); // Esperar a que se complete el clic derecho y se recogan los datos antes de continuar
                    // Agregar el elemento al conjunto de elementos clickeados
                    elementosClickeados.add(elemento);
                    // Esperar 1 segundo antes de hacer clic derecho en el siguiente elemento
                    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
                }
            }
            console.log("Bucle de observación y actualización en ejecución."); // Agregar un mensaje de registro para verificar que el bucle sigue ejecutándose
        }
    }
    
        // Llamar a la función principal
        hacerScrollYClickInfinito();
```

---

Script that subsequently does not find the div with the word car `item__183e8.labelContainer_bc2861.colorDanger_eec36d.colorDefault__0b482`

```js
        async function hacerScrollYClickInfinito() {
        // Conjunto para almacenar los elementos ya clickeados dos veces
        const elementosClickeados = new Set();
    
        // Función para hacer clic derecho en un elemento y recoger el texto de los spans
        async function hacerClickDerechoYRecogerTexto(elemento) {
            try {
                // Hacer clic derecho en el elemento
                elemento.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('contextmenu', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
                console.log("Clic derecho en el elemento realizado con éxito.");
    
                // Esperar 0.4 segundos
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 400));
    
                // Buscar el div específico después del clic derecho
                const divsBuscados = elemento.querySelectorAll('.item__183e8.labelContainer_bc2861.colorDanger_eec36d.colorDefault__0b482');
                divsBuscados.forEach(div => {
                    if (div.querySelector('div') && div.querySelector('div').innerText.includes('coche')) {
                        elemento.click(); // Hacer clic izquierdo sobre el elemento si contiene "Banear" en algún div interno
                        console.log("Clic izquierdo en el elemento encontrado realizado con éxito.");
                    }
                });
    
                // Imprimir el texto de los elementos span dentro del div
                var spans = elemento.querySelectorAll('span');
                spans.forEach(span => {
                    console.log("Texto del span:", span.textContent);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error al hacer clic derecho en el elemento:", error.message);
            }
        }
    
        // Función para hacer scroll sobre el elemento
        function hacerScrollSobreElemento() {
            // Hacer scroll hacia abajo en el div
            var divScroll = document.querySelector('.members__9f47b.thin_b1c063.scrollerBase_dc3aa9.fade_ba0fa0.customTheme_db4d28');
            divScroll.scrollTop += 40; // Cambia este valor según sea necesario para el scroll deseado
        }
    
        // Función para esperar a que los elementos se carguen
        async function esperarElementosCargados() {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // Esperar 2 segundos para asegurar que los elementos estén cargados
        }
    
        // Bucle principal
        while (true) {
            await esperarElementosCargados();
    
            // Obtener los elementos ya presentes en la página
            var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.memberInner_a32223.layout_bb8e67');
            for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
                const elemento = elementos[i];
                // Verificar si el elemento ha sido clickeado dos veces previamente
                if (!elementosClickeados.has(elemento)) {
                    hacerScrollSobreElemento(); // Hacer scroll sobre el elemento antes de hacer clic
                    await hacerClickDerechoYRecogerTexto(elemento); // Esperar a que se complete el clic derecho y se recogan los datos antes de continuar
                    // Agregar el elemento al conjunto de elementos clickeados
                    elementosClickeados.add(elemento);
                    // Esperar 1 segundo antes de hacer clic derecho en el siguiente elemento
                    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
                }
            }
            console.log("Bucle de observación y actualización en ejecución."); // Agregar un mensaje de registro para verificar que el bucle sigue ejecutándose
        }
    }
    
    // Llamar a la función principal
    hacerScrollYClickInfinito();
```

Comment: Where is your html?

Comment: I can't find where you compare text `Car` in your js?

Comment: Do you mean the literal text, "Car" or the literal text, "coche"?